# TFS - Branching

Tags: tfs, tfvc

I am doing to for the first time so I want to use Release isolation strategy for our project using TFVC. I went over documentation on how to do that but I was unable to branch out our projects. We have two projects which are dependent on each other and structure of those projects looks like this:

1. Project 1

   - folder 1
   - folder 2
   - folder 3

I tried to convert project itself to branch and then branching it out but it gives me an error saying `TF10175: ... Team project does not exist.` Then I tried to create one main folder inside the project and convert that folder into branch and then branch it out but reorganizing folders causing build issues. Do you have any advice how I could branch my projects out and why am I getting team project does not exist issue. Do I need to create new project in TFS called XYZ-branch?

Comment: You're using TFS, but which version control system are you using? TFSVC, or Git? And if you're not using Git...why not?

Comment: @mason sorry edited my question using TFVC, haven't looked into Git, will check it out, thanks.

Comment: As you discovered, you can't create a branch from the team project root, i.e. `$/MyTeamProjectName`. You already found the correct solution: Create a folder underneath the team project root and branch from that. You had issues with your builds after you created a branch. So is your *actual* issue "How do I fix my builds?"

Comment: @DanielMann I see, thank you, then will create a folder and will try to solve build issues.